# RegEx to find a string before the last semi-colon

Tags: regex

I have the following regex [`/\.(\w+)/g` represented here](https://regex101.com/r/55OhEd/3)

It's matching against this sample string: `function () {__cov_0vpZ06dQffa98X1ZQ0lWVA.f['74']++;__cov_0vpZ06dQffa98X1ZQ0lWVA.s['211']++;return t.propertygroup.subproperty1;}`

Right now it's matching "f.s.propertygroup.subproperty1", but I want it to match only "propertyGroup.subproperty1" or if it was just t.subproperty1 it would just match "subproperty1". So it should find all words after the first period, but only before the last occurrence of the semi-colon.

The function string above is dynamic (JavaScript) so it might add additional statements with additional semi-colons at any time, but I still want to match only the last return variable name.

I've been fighting this regex all day and you, a regex guru, could probably solve this in 5 minutes. Can you help?

Comment: Are there more complex examples than the one listed here?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead:

```
\.(\w+)(?=[^;]*;[^;]*$)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/55OhEd/4)

The `(?=[^;]*;[^;]*$)` will only match the `.` + word chars if they are followed with 0+ chars other than `;`, then `;` and again 0+ chars other than `;` up to the end of string.

JS code:

```js
var regex = /\.(\w+)(?=[^;]*;[^;]*$)/g;
var str = "function () {__cov_0vpZ06dQffa98X1ZQ0lWVA.f['74']++;__cov_0vpZ06dQffa98X1ZQ0lWVA.s['211']++;return t.propertygroup.subproperty1;}";
var res = [], m;
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
   res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Or another one:

```js
var s = "function () {__cov_0vpZ06dQffa98X1ZQ0lWVA.f['74']++;__cov_0vpZ06dQffa98X1ZQ0lWVA.s['211']++;return t.propertygroup.subproperty1;}";
var res = s.match(/\.(\w+)(?=[^;]*;[^;]*$)/g).map(function(x) {return x.slice(1);});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This matches a period in front of `propertygroup.subproperty1`

Comment: @Jim, please check my approach and if it is not what you mean, please let me know.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the only problem is that the function is dynamic. It has an indeterminate number of semicolons, so I don't know that there will only be three. I'll edit my question to state that. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by only 3? I only extract word char chunks before the *final* `;` (if there is one, else, there are no matches). Please provide some example to show what these dynamic theme is about.

Comment: Again, I'm no RegEx expert, which is why I'm posting this question. I misinterpreted your answer. I added additional statements with additional semicolons and it still works! As @NicolasMaltais says, it would be nice to remove the leading period, but I can take that out later. I'll accept this one. Thanks!

Comment: You do not have to *remove* any periods, just access the Group 1 contents. Where are you using the regex? Is it used in JavaScript? I added the JS demo.

Comment: So THAT is how you get at groups. I was trying to get it in RegEx. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this is the one you need?

```
@"\.([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)[^;]*;[^;]*}$"
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/J0FMHw/1)